# array value in do while loop is not passing to the next

Tags: c++, arrays

I am fairly new to c++ and am having trouble passing an array through a do while loop and calculating the average. Below is my code, would someone point me in the right direction?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int marks[5], sum = 0, g, avg=0;
    do {
        cout << "enter a mark: ";
        cin >> marks[g];
        if (marks[g] < 0 || marks[g] > 100)
            "Invalid Mark, start over";
        marks[g++];
    } while(g <= 5);
    do {
        sum += marks[g++];
        avg = sum/5;
    } while(g <= 5);
    cout << "The average of the marks is: " << avg << endl;
}
```

Comment: Uninitialized (non-static) local variables have an indeterminate value, using them except to initialize them leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: [I have a dream](http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2015/02/i-have-dream-im-dreaming-of-so-called-c.html)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ And in addition, every single instructor shows an example with `using namespace std`, which is terrible!!

Comment: @Cyber Yeah! Most of the instructors/teachers render just being incompetent IMHO, and start to teach their students bridling from the rear.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I have only been programming for 1 month and I appreciate the feedback. So far we have only learned examples with "using namespace std;", what should i be using instead?

Answer (score 3):

You never initialized your index variable `g`, you should initialize it to

```
int g = 0;
```

Also I would recommend your first loop be something like

```
while (g < 5)
{
    int value;
    cout << "enter a mark: ";
    cin >> value;

    if (value < 0 || value > 100)
    {
        "Invalid Mark, enter again";
    }
    else
    {
        marks[g] = value;
        ++g;
    }
}
```

Similarly the last loop would be

```
for {int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{    
    sum += marks[i];
}
avg = sum/5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, initialize `g` to 0 using

```
int g = 0;
```

Secondly, change

```
while(g <= 5);
```

to

```
while(g < 5);
```

because as `marks[]` has a size of 5, the accessible indexes are from 0 to 4.

Corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int marks[5], sum = 0, g = 0, avg=0;
    do
    {
        cout << "enter a mark: ";
        cin >> marks[g];

        if (marks[g] < 0 || marks[g] > 100)
        {
            "Invalid Mark, start over";
        }
        else g++;
    }
    while(g < 5);
g = 0; //Set g to zero to restart counting.
do {

    sum += marks[g++];
    avg = sum/5;
}
while(g < 5);
cout << "The average of the marks is: " << avg << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

variable g is not initialized properly. also array accessed out of bound. proper code should be:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int marks[5], sum = 0, g = 0, avg=0;

    do
    {
        cout << "enter a mark: ";
        cin >> marks[g];

        if (marks[g] < 0 || marks[g] > 100)
        {
            "Invalid Mark, start over";
        }
        else
            marks[g++];

    }
    while(g < 5);
    g = 0;

    do {

        sum += marks[g++];
        avg = sum/5;
    }
    while(g < 5);

    cout << "The average of the marks is: " << avg << endl;

    system("pause");

}
```